# URL rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not familiar with url rewrite at all, so I have probably simple question for somebody that knows the stuff.
I have ecommerce site and currently item url looks like this
www.blizuecomm.net/www/item.php?id=399&ITEM-NAME
I get this kind of URL with code on category page that looks like this

```
<a href="item.php?id=<?=$values[$i]['gitemid']?>&amp;<?=cleanString($values[$i]['gname'])?>
```

I get clean string using this code

```
<?
function cleanString($string, $separator = '-'){
$accents = array('Š' => 'S', 'š' => 's', '?' => 'Dj', 'ð' => 'dj','Ž' => 'Z', 'ž' => 'z', 'È' => 'C' , 'è' => 'c', 'Æ' => 'C' , 'æ' => 'c');
$string = strtr($string, $accents);
$string = strtoupper($string);
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('{ +}', ' ', $string);
$string = trim($string);
$string = str_replace(' ', $separator, $string);
return $string;
}
?>
```

What should I write in .htaccess file in order to get ULR that looks like this:
www.blizuecomm.net/www/ITEM-NAME
or
www.blizuecomm.net/ITEM-NAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably make it look like: `www.blizuecomm.net/www/id/ITEM-NAME` because otherwise your `item.php` script isn't going to get an ID. That'll require you to add this in the htaccess file **in your `www` folder**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /www/item\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ item.php?id=$1&$2 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: www.blizuecomm.net/www/id/ITEM-NAME?id=id&ITEM-NAME am i missing something or should i search for err in code ? Thanks

Comment: @sz_tech sorry, I left out a question mark at the end of `%2`

Comment: Thanks Jon works like I asked, do You have an idea what should I check since now when URL rewrite is successful I can see that my styles and images are not working on the page.

Comment: @sz_tech either make the links of your styles/images absolute URLs, or add a relative base to the page header: `<base href="/">` (or whatever the base should be)